# LaTeX Error: Bad math environment delimiter

Tags: math-mode

This is my equation:

```
\begin{equation}
H(p)=-p\log(p)-(1-p)\log(1-p) 
\end{equation}
```

and this is the error:

```
Your command was ignored.
Type I <command> <return> to replace it with another command,
or <return> to continue without it.
! Missing \endgroup inserted.
<inserted text>
 \endgroup
l.319 \end{equation}

I've inserted something that you may have forgotten.
(See the <inserted text> above.)
With luck, this will get me unwedged. But if you
really didn't forget anything, try typing `2' now; then
my insertion and my current dilemma will both disappear.
Overfull \hbox (17.77782pt too wide) detected at line 319
 []
[]
Overfull \hbox (514.90825pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 316--319
[]\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 where $\OML/cmm/m/it/10
^^Misahyperparameterrangingbetween\OT
1/cmr/m/n/10 0\OML/cmm/m/it/10 and\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 1\OML/cmm/m/it/10
:$\OT1/cmr/
m/it/10 H(p)$\OML/cmm/m/it/10
denotestheShannonentropyand$\OT1/cmr/m/it/10 p$\O
ML/cmm/m/it/10 istheoutputofEncoder;
whichisthepropensityscore:$\OT1/cmr/m/it/1
0 H(p)$\OML/cmm/m/it/10 isrepresentedbythefollowingequation
\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 : [
]\OML/cmm/m/it/10 H\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 (\OML/cmm/m/it/10 p\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 ) =
[]
```

---

and this is the text before equation:

```
\begin{equation}
\text{Dropout Probability}(x)=1-\frac{\gamma}{2}-\frac{1}{2} H(\hat{p}(x,t))
\end{equation}

where \textit{\gamma} is a hyperparameter ranging between 0 and 1. 
$H(p)$ denotes the Shannon entropy and $p$ is the output of 
Encoder, which is the propensity score. $H(p)$ is represented 
by the following equation:
\begin{equation}
H(p)=-p\log(p)-(1-p)\log(1-p) 
\end{equation}
```

Comment: When i search the relate question, almostly about "\begin{equation}" and "\[" you need choose only one.

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  Your equation looks okay, but there may be something earlier in your file that isn't resolved until the `\end{equation}`.  So more information is needed.  Please show at least the `\documentclass`, the packages you're using, and a few paragraphs of text that precede the equation.  Although a compilable example would be best, if your file compiles locally for you, that would be hard to construct.  But do check your log file for anything else it might tell you before this error, and report that here.

Comment: \documentclass[sn-mathphys,fleqn]{sn-jnl}, \usepackage[caption=false]{subfig} \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} \usepackage{amsmath}\usepackage[ruled,linesnumbered,boxed,commentsnumbered,algo2e,vlined]{algorithm2e}

Comment: and this is the text before equation:

\begin{equation} \text{Dropout Probability}(x)=1-\frac{\gamma}{2}-\frac{1}{2} H(\hat{p}(x,t)) \end{equation}

where \textit{\gamma} is a hyperparameter ranging between 0 and 1. $H(p)$ denotes the Shannon entropy and $p$ is the output of Encoder, which is the propensity score. $H(p)$ is represented by the following equation: \begin{equation} H(p)=-p\log(p)-(1-p)\log(1-p) \end{equation}

Comment: `\textit{\gamma}` is completely wrong. It should almost certainly be `$\gamma$`. Hint: `\gamma` is a math-mode only macro, and `\textit` is, well, a text-mode macro. In TeX and LaTeX, `$` has a special meaning: it's used to enter into and exit from inline math mode. Hence, do give `$\gamma$` a try.

Comment: okay, thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

The error shown

```
! Missing \endgroup inserted.
<inserted text>
 \endgroup
l.319 \end{equation}
```

is unusual, but indicates that probably the math scoping is out of proper sequence.  There should have been an earlier error in the `.log` file -- *always* check the log file, and address errors in the order in which they appear.  And to help the helpers here, more  information is needed, preferably a small but compilable example that produces the error.

Fortunately, the paragraph preceding the equation contained the source of the error -- `\textit{gamma}`.  Since `\gamma` is exclusively math, it needed to be enclosed in `$...$` to indicate a math expression.  That would produce a more understandable error message in the log, and making that one correction solved the problem.

I'm closing this question, and have provided this answer only because the reported error message is an unusual one.